Could an organism breathe SO2 (Sulfur Dioxide) and reuse the sulfur atom for bones made of S8 (Octasulfur) and AlO3 (Aluminium Oxide)?
Problem
Background
I want animals on my fictional planet to use 6 SO2 (Sulfur Dioxide) instead of 6 O2 (Oxygen) to react with C6H12O6 (Glucose), to make 6 CO2 (Carbon Dioxide), ATP, 6 H2O (Water), and 6 extra Sulfur atoms. After the process of cellular respiration is repeated 4 times, the 24 extra sulfur atoms are made into 3 S8 (Octasulfur), and combined with some amount of AlO3 (Aluminium Oxide) to form the animals bones. 
Difficulty
AlO3 can react with S8 to form Al2S3 and O2. I am not sure how this process happens, like if you need it to combust or something else, but i need to figure out what their bones are made of and if it can actually scientifically work. Also, if this even works what color would it end up being? Would it be strong enough to support an animal about as heavy as a blue whale (~150 Metric Tons)? If it doesn't work, would a compound of sodium or iron or even a sulfate work instead and meet the requirements?

Well consider for example that glucose can be burned to produce CO2 and water vapor, but that doesn't mean our bodies process it that way. Enzymes can kind of hand wave away a lot of chemical transformations. On wikipedia it mentions that reacting pure aluminum with sulfur is exothermic and will proceed on its own, so the only thing to worry about is reducing the aluminum oxide to pure aluminum and that's not too hard to do. As to the color, aluminum sulfide looks to be white, so the color will depend on what else goes into making the bones. A lot of what you're asking is just a bit too diffic

pure aluminum with sulfur is exothermic will proceed on its own, but OP is asking about aluminum oxide

Yes. I said that. So, as I stated in my original post, the next thing to look into is how difficult it is to reduce aluminum oxide into pure aluminum. All in all it looks like a reasonable process when assisted by biological mechanisms

I've only seen AlS3 as a powder on google images, can it still be solid?

I'd recommend looking up chemicals Wikipedia pages in the future. If it's simple enough or well known for some other reason, there's often a lot of information on there. The wiki page says that when produced by heating sulfur and aluminum, the product forms gets hot enough to melt together and when it cools it is a fused, very hard solid. It also mentions that it reacts with water and decomposes to produce hydrated aluminum oxides and hydrogen sulfide. So if your animals are going to be using water like life on earth, it could be a problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_sulfide

@L.Dutch The formation of Al2S3 from Al2O3 and S8 is extremely endothermic, something around 7616 kJ/mol. That reaction forming the bones (if Al2S3 can even form bones) will probably be much more costly than the amount of energy produced per mol in the metabolism. As such, the Al2S3 probably won’t form in the first place.

This is what happens when you colonize a planet with sulfur-reducing bacteria.  The progenitor strains were selected from an acid mine drainage remediation project.  Abundant SO2 in the atmosphere reacts with water to produce sulfurous acid:  H2O + SO2 -> H2SO3.  This can serve as an electron acceptor: 6H+ + 6e- + H2SO3 -> 3H2O + H2S.  The electrons are delivered from the mitochondrial electron transport chain after the breakdown of glucose as for more familiar organisms.
Some of the energy these organisms generate can be used to carry out digestion and cellular biochemistry, which might include breaking down the abundant corundum sands in the environment.  The organism uses a number of highly optimized enzymes, using amino acids that contain a range of transition metal catalysts which have been added to its genetic code.  The purpose of these enzymes is to temporarily break down aluminum oxide into unstable aluminum sulfide, which is then converted back to aluminum oxide to make powerful, immense skeletons of corundum.  (The cells involved contain granules of octasulfur as a mode of storage)  Resembling Earthly corundum brick, the organisms' corundum skeletons can be white, ruby, sapphire, or many other colors depending on the impurities present; however, the skeletal plates of corundum adorning their outer skin are typically patterned with structural color giving them a beautiful, iridescent quality.

You're asking for the reaction of Aluminum Oxide (Al2O3, there isn't ALO3 that's stable to begin with) + 3S8 -> AL2S3 + 3O2.
Let's just ignore the 3O2 part and talk about the AL2S3, which is going to be your problem.
First, you need to somehow break apart the AL2O3 (Which is a very stable compound and is normally chemically inert). We can assume you have some sort of reducing agent, for example, Carbon, and handwave the energy requirements for the chain.
That gives you AL2O3 + 3C -> 2AL + 3CO. (This would require temperatures around 2000c).
Then you can do 2AL + 3S -> AL2S3 (Which also needs high temperatures, since you need to vaporize the sulfur (boiling point 444c).
Even assuming you could get the energy requirements to complete this already very expensive reaction chain, creating AL2S3 as the last step here generates temperatures over 1100c. While this is less than the reduction step requiring 2000c, even if you could find a different reduction agent (or a different path, eg Hall-Heroult with electrolysis), your creature has to survive internal temperatures of over 1100c. You'd be talking about some sort of hyperthermophile that can survive at 10x the record temperature that we have of bacterial hyperthermophiles (130c).
That being said, you can handwave away a lot of stuff with specialized alien organs. At the end of the day, it's your story.
Can it work? Tl;DR: Probably not

Many of the reactions in the human body "need high temperatures", if we didn't have enzymes.  For example, sugar to carbon dioxide would burn at a high temperature.  Provided this life form has enzymes, it should avoid the requirements you expect.  But the reaction still takes a lot of energy to make a much less stable product than Al2O3.

On the matter of stability, aluminum sulfide reacts with water to form aluminum oxides/hydroxides and hydrogen sulfide. This isn't an ideal property for a bone mineral.

I agree with both of your comments, which is also why I said he could handwave a lot of stuff away with specialized alien organs. I still maintain that the answer here is that it probably does not work.
